# I want to get the thumbnail of the photo I captured using my app

Tags: android, android-intent, thumbnails

I want to get the thumbnail of the photo I captured using my app. But I am not getting it using the following code. Please help. 
Here is the code:

```
 Intent i = new
Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
file.mkdirs();
File image = new File(file, "picture1" + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

final int THUMBSIZE = 64;
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath()),
                    THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);

startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

See the official guide for more information https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html